# Cannot import name 'SGD' from 'keras.optimizers' when importing talos

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, talos

I am trying to import talos python module using `import talos`
this is the error I get:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SGD' from 'keras.optimizers'

I have solved the same error message before when I used `from keras.optimizers import Adam,Nadam, SGD` changing the code to `from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam,Nadam, SGD`. However, the error message I get now is within the internal talos import command. talos 0.4.8, keras 2.2.4, tensorflow 2.6.0
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Talos 0.4.8 supports Tensorflow 2.0.0

Install latest version of Talos==1.0, which supports Tensorflow 2.6.0.

`from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam,Nadam, SGD` and `import talos` works just fine with talos 1.0 and Tensorflow 2.6.0.